# VSCode not showing suggested code for MonoDevelop/Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, monodevelop, omnisharp

**Someone kindly help why does VSCode doesn't show suggested code for MonoDevelop/Unity/C#** Under is the code shown in the photo and whats the VSCode is not suggesting.Also there some weird Error for OmniSharp which i don't know why its happening!
[image: VSCode Suggestion Not Working]
[image: VSCode Problem]
[image: OmniSharp Problem]
[image: OmniSharp Error]

Comment: Try Roslynator.

Comment: I did nothing happened!

Comment: Isto já aconteceu diversas vezes comigo, é muito frustrante. Acontece que está gerando erros no Ominsharp, nas vezes que aconteceu comigo foi por causa do .NET Framework não estava na versão correta, vá até o site da microsoft e tente baixar a ultima versão do .NET Framework, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework.

Comment: Omg so so thank you @PokeClash

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I had answered in the wrong language. But I hope you solved the problem.

Comment: No problem i just translated your language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me several times, it's very frustrating. It turns out that it is generating errors in Ominsharp, the times it happened to me it was because the .NET Framework was not in the correct version, go to the microsoft website and try to download the latest version of the .NET Framework, [dotnet.microsoft.com/download /dotnet-framework.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework)

Comment: Omg Thanks So Much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed some of the extensions required. Go to Extension and then type an AI that you wish to use. I suggest either Kite or Tabnine. Both of them are great Ai.